1990's Twilight Zone-esque show for kids
I remember watching a TV show when I was a kid (in the 1990's) that was very reminiscent to The Twilight Zone, where different things would happen in each episode without a story arch connecting everything, as far as I remember.
The one episode that really stands out is an episode where a male highschooler, needing dry underwear, throws it into a microwave to dry it out.  When it comes out, it's sparkly.  I believe it made him able to either run or swim faster.  I am unsure if there was a negative consequence at the end of the episode, but I feel that there probably was something.  Maybe the underwear got too small?
The show is NOT: 

Are You Afraid of the Dark
The Third Eye


Quick Details:

American, in English, in Color, Live Action
Would have been on Nickelodeon or other similar kid's programming
Early to mid 1990's


This is an episode of Round The Twist, but the show did have an arc. From the Paley Center:

One in this children's series made in Australia about a family that lives in a town populated by ghosts and elemental spirits. In this episode, Pete plans to enter Bronson's frog in a frog race in the hopes it will beat the frog entered by his cruel-hearted classmate, Gribble. Being late for school, Pete dries his underwear in the microwave. He later discovers that the garment has taken on magical powers that endow him with super strength and extraordinary abilities. He finds that he can crush rocks with his bare hands, lift the school bus off the ground, throw Gribble through the locker room wall, outrun the fastest runner in his class (who happens to be the girl of his dreams), and impress an audience of Japanese developers as he shows off his super abilities by doing stunts in the ocean. Unfortunately, the water causes his underwear to shrink to the size of his thumb, leaving him completely naked. 

The episode is "Wunderpants" from 1989 (Season 1, Episode 8) and you can see it here. The intro:




I wasn't QUITE sure, until I saw the girl in the karate outfit, then I was like "YUP, this is it!"

As a child, I was really fond and used to LMAO to the episode where the boy is cursed to have to end every sentence with: "without my pants". That was a good show.
